# VS Code ignores global `tabSize` setting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Relevant user settings:

```
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
```

Workspace settings are empty. Using VS Code 1.52.0.

.cpp files get formatted properly (using the `Format Document` option), yet in .py files it changes all indents to 4 spaces and inserts some unnecessary vertical spacing (like, double empty lines in some places). The only settings specific to Python are `pythonPath` and `condaPath`.

Edit: Inserting this:

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
  "--ignore",
  "E301, E302, E305, E306, E101, E11"
],
```

into `settings.json` stops it from changing 2 space indents into 4 space indents, but now it just ignores indentation altogether. I want it to correct indentation to 2 spaces. Used [this](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#features) for reference.

Edit: I want this:
[image]
to be fixed to this:
[image]
but it gets fixed like this instead:
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide us with examples or screenshots that minimize the reproduction of this problem and the format you want?

Comment: Added screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following settings in "`settings.json`":

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--indent-size=2"],
```

[image]

Related settings I use:

```
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--indent-size=2"],
```